# How to Make a PUT request to Elastic Search with a JSON file using REST Template

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am creating a SpringBoot Application, where I need to PUT a JSON schema in Elastic Search. The JSON schema will be in my resources folder(in my classpath). How to PUT the raw JSON file using REST Template.

Any Help?" As most of the example on internet are JUST assuming that we have a POJO class to send. But here I am not aware about the JSON Schema. I need to make the request with the raw JSON file.

Comment: Sure. please put JSON schema sample. & which elasticsearch version you are using & why do you want to put json in elasticsearch. Then i can help you.

Comment: Hi, The JSON schema is actually defining the data structure of data , which I am going to index in elastic search. https://qbox.io/blog/how-to-index-json-with-elasticsearch. It will define the mapping only. This JSON is not the data I am trying to index. The ES version is 2.4.0

Comment: Then, can you share your sudo code where you want to create index. don't worry about mapping if you create json structure to store in elasticsearch then which will elastic automatically creates mapping if you want to modify it then use the code provided by Rahul (because i don't know your schema structure then how can i give you solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the json schema contains the mapping/settings for an index. Then you can put the mapping like as shown below :

```
CreateIndexRequestBuilder createIndexRequestBuilder = client.admin().indices().prepareCreate(index);
// CREATE MAPPING
String mapping_json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(json_mapping_path));
createIndexRequestBuilder.addMapping("my_mapping", mapping_json);
CreateIndexResponse indexResponse = createIndexRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
```

Answer (score 1):

For create index don't worry about index mapping json if you wish your json will not be changed ever you can directly create documents by using this code

```
for(listObject lObject:list){
 XContentBuilder json;
try {
        json = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
        json.startObject();// Main Object Start
        json.field(GlobalSearchCosntants.DOCUMENT_ID, lObject.getId());
        json.field(GlobalSearchCosntants.DOCUMENT_NAME, lObject.getName());
        json.field(GlobalSearchCosntants.DOCUMENT_TYPE, lObject.getType());
        json.endObject();// Main Object Start
}catch (IOException e1) {
        logger.error("Problem while creating document " + e1.getMessage());
}

client.prepareIndex(INDEX_NAME, GlobalSearchCosntants.INDEX_TYPE, id)
                    .setSource(json).execute().actionGet();
}
```